How do I fold a function over the bindings in a map in Isabelle?
Coq has the FMap modules, is there a similar Isabelle theory module?
https://coq.inria.fr/doc/v8.19/stdlib/Coq.FSets.FMapInterface.html
What I want to be able to do is fold a function over the bindings in a map, and look up keys.
The maps in Main have no way to do folding, and the AList and Mapping theories only supply a few functions. They seem to have no lookup functions. I've been looking through the HOL library, and can't find anything that seems applicable.
